# How to do a Throwable call in a flatMap in RxJava2?

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm working with RxJava2 and I was doing simple request, I should do it like the next example:

```
getCompositeDisposable().add(subscriptionManager.getSubscriptions(getUserAuth().getToken()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Consumer<HttpCustomRes<List<GetSubscriptions>>>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(@NonNull HttpCustomRes<List<GetSubscriptions>> listHttpCustomRes) throws Exception {

                getMvpView().hideLoading();

                ErrorCode errorCaught = bypassForErrors(listHttpCustomRes.getError());

                if(errorCaught.equals(ErrorCode.SUCCESSFUL_REPSONSE))
                    getMvpView().showSubscriptions(listHttpCustomRes.getData());
                else if(errorCaught.equals(ErrorCode.INVALID_TOKEN) || errorCaught.equals(ErrorCode.NULL_TOKEN))
                    getMvpView().showLogin();
                else
                    getMvpView().showErrorDialog();

            }
        }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {

                getMvpView().hideLoading();
                getMvpView().showErrorDialog();

            }
        }));
```

Now, I need to do two sequential request, so I'm using the flatMap to do this. In the simple request I have the second call to the method new Consumer to catch errors, but with the flatMap I don't know how to do this. I post the code in the next lines.

```
getCompositeDisposable().add(accountUserManager.getUserData(getUserAuth().getToken()).flatMap(new Function<UserData, Flowable<HttpCustomRes<List<GetSubscriptions>>>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Flowable<HttpCustomRes<List<GetSubscriptions>>> apply(@NonNull UserData userData) throws Exception {

                        setUserData(userData);

                        return subscriptionManager.getSubscriptions(getUserAuth().getToken());
                    }
                }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Consumer<HttpCustomRes<List<GetSubscriptions>>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(@NonNull HttpCustomRes<List<GetSubscriptions>> listHttpCustomRes) throws Exception {

                        getMvpView().hideLoading();

                        ErrorCode errorCaught = bypassForErrors(listHttpCustomRes.getError());

                        if(errorCaught.equals(ErrorCode.SUCCESSFUL_REPSONSE))
                            getMvpView().showSubscriptions(listHttpCustomRes.getData());
                        else if(errorCaught.equals(ErrorCode.INVALID_TOKEN) || errorCaught.equals(ErrorCode.NULL_TOKEN))
                            getMvpView().showLogin();
                        else
                            getMvpView().showErrorDialog();

                    }
                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {

                        getMvpView().hideLoading();
                        getMvpView().showErrorDialog();

                    }
                })
        );
```

As you can see, I have a throwable in the second method, but not in the first, so if the first crash, the app will crash too. How I can implement the throwable to the first request?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All unchecked exception ([well, almost all](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/12/08/error-handling-in-rxjava/)) will be delivered to the `onError` handler in the subscriber which is the second Consumer in your subscribe method.
Thus in your case, both exception in the source `getUserData` Observable and the `flatMap` mapping function will be handled by the stream and will be delivered to the `onError` handler.

Comment: Then, my code is well-constructed? So, the second consumer extending the Throwable will handle the both possible errors? It is what I'm understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
 new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                        try{
                        getMvpView().hideLoading();
                        getMvpView().showErrorDialog();
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            throw e;
                        }
                    }
                })
```